# Camel SQL component - simple select query result

Tags: sql, apache-camel

I'm working with Apache Camel and I've been facing a problem with the sql component.
I could only perform an insert query but a simple select query wouldn't return anything.
The Datasource is configured properly and I have no errors. 
I read that the result of a select query is List> but I always have blank results.

Here's my camel route:

```
from("direct:start")        
    .to("sql:select * from infos where id=1 ?dataSourceRef=myDataSource")
    .beanRef("MBean","monitor")
    .to("log:result");
```

And here is the method I'm trying to use to process the result:

```
public Object monitor(Exchange exchange){

    List<Map<String,Object>> l= (List<Map<String,Object>>) exchange.getOut().getBody();
    Map<String,Object> map = l.get(0);
    Object str = map.get("msg");
    exchange.getIn().setBody(str);
    return str;
}
```

I'm really stuck ..

Comment: In your method `monitor(Exchange ex)` try to use `exchange.getIn()` instead of `exchange.getOut()`.

Comment: Yes and see also this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

Comment: Thank you I'll try it.
In fact I switched to using the jdbc component for the moment because I needed to progress but I'll get back to that

Comment: It's still not working ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It worked for me.

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    List<HashMap> out = (ArrayList<HashMap>) exchange.getIn().getBody();

            try{
                for(HashMap outContent:out){
                    String message = outContent.get("output_obj").toString();

                    System.out.println(message);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }   
}
```